# track gets very slow after generating it in my code

Tags: android, audio

what could have made this generation of a track get too slow?

Basically I'm creating a track in the audio format: "wav".

But after completing the track it is in slow motion.

What can set the speed of a track?

```
 resume of the code:

    for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) 
    {
        if ( i <= arrayMusic1.length - 1)
            samplef1 = arrayMusic1[i] / 128.0f; 

        if ( i <= arrayMusic2.length - 1)
            samplef2 = arrayMusic2[i] / 128.0f;

        output[i]          = outputSample;  

     } 

public void saveToFile(byte[] output, String globalName, String nameMix) 
{
        long mySubChunk1Size = 16;
        int myBitsPerSample  = 16;
        int myFormat         = 1;
        long myChannels      = 1;
        long mySampleRate    = 44400;
        long myByteRate      = mySampleRate * myChannels * myBitsPerSample /8;
        int myBlockAlign     = (int) (myChannels * myBitsPerSample/8);
        //long teste           = output.length;
        long myDataSize      = output.length - 100000;//output.length  //aqui ta o problema
        long myChunk2Size    = myDataSize * myChannels * myBitsPerSample/8;
        long myChunkSize     = 36 + myChunk2Size;

        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/ssmultitrackPlus/"+globalName.trim()+"/"+nameMix+".wav"));
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
        DataOutputStream outFile = new DataOutputStream(bos);

        outFile.writeBytes("RIFF");                                     // 00 - RIFF
        outFile.write(intToByteArray((int)myChunkSize), 0, 4);          // 04 - how big is the rest of this file?
        outFile.writeBytes("WAVE");                                     // 08 - WAVE
        outFile.writeBytes("fmt ");                                     // 12 - fmt 
        outFile.write(intToByteArray((int)mySubChunk1Size), 0, 4);      // 16 - size of this chunk
        outFile.write(shortToByteArray((short)myFormat), 0, 2);         // 20 - what is the audio format? 1 for PCM = Pulse Code Modulation
        outFile.write(shortToByteArray((short)myChannels), 0, 2);       // 22 - mono or stereo? 1 or 2?  (or 5 or ???)
        outFile.write(intToByteArray((int)mySampleRate), 0, 4);         // 24 - samples per second (numbers per second)
        outFile.write(intToByteArray((int)myByteRate), 0, 4);           // 28 - bytes per second
        outFile.write(shortToByteArray((short)myBlockAlign), 0, 2);     // 32 - # of bytes in one sample, for all channels
        outFile.write(shortToByteArray((short)myBitsPerSample), 0, 2);  // 34 - how many bits in a sample(number)?  usually 16 or 24
        outFile.writeBytes("data");                                     // 36 - data
        outFile.write(intToByteArray((int)myDataSize), 0, 4);           // 40 - how big is this data chunk
        outFile.write(output);                                          // 44 - the actual data itself - just a long string of numbers

        outFile.flush();
        outFile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Byterate must be `mySampleRate*myChannels*2` and function to write byterate mast be look like:

`writeInt(output, mySampleRate*2); // byte rate because 16bit and 1 channel`

```
public static void writeInt(final DataOutputStream output, final int value) throws IOException {
    output.write(value >> 0);
    output.write(value >> 8);
    output.write(value >> 16);
    output.write(value >> 24);
}
```

Standart samplerate audio CD quality is 44100. If audio slows down without any artifacts like "popcorn" then problem with samplerate or byterate in header. You may look what actually was recorded with some binary/hex reader/writer app like [GHex](https://github.com/GNOME/ghex). Also for PCM there should be choosed 1.

Comment: This! To explain, I was mixing two tracks.

Problem, one with 1 channel and one with 2 channels.

Result, track in slow motion or too fast.

Comment: How do you mix them? You need to convert 2 channels to mono and then work in mono mode or 1 channel track convert to double mono (2 channels with the same mono data in each) and work further with two channels tracks.

Comment: I edited the code a bit, but basically I run the arrays with the tracks.
Yes, I am able to convert using FFMPEG, I just have to figure out how to choose the conversion channel.
I'm using:
https://github.com/adrielcafe/AndroidAudioConverter

Comment: For wav with 16 bits sample and two channels data will come: 2 bytes Left Channel, 2 bytes Right Channel, 2 bytes LC, 2 bytes RC ... To covert short value of sample you have to use:
public static byte[] shortArrToByteArr(short[] array) {
        byte[] res = new byte[array.length*2];

        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < array.length; i++, j+=2) {
            res[j] = (byte) (array[i]&0xFF);
            res[j+1] = (byte) ((array[i] >>> 8)&0xFF);
        }
        return res;
    }

Comment: in the end I used ffmpeg and converted everything to the same format, and it worked, thank you for the help guy